# Simple Java Questions: "Subarrays" and "refressing" assigned variables;

Tags: java

I'm very new to java, only have taken one class, and am looking for more efficient ways to do things.

A. Do subarrays exist? I would like to assign to a new array, the elements within a range of another array.

The only way I've been taught is:

```
int[] a = {a, b, c, d}; 
int[] b = {a[0], a[1]};
```

Is there something similar to variable.substring(stop,end)?

B. This one is hard to explain. If I have two variables, a and b, with b = a + 1(for example), and I change a, I have to reassign b = a + 1, or else b will equal whatever it did before I changed a. Is there a way to "refresh" b using the new value of a, without typing b = a + 1(or something far more complicated) every single time?

This is less for function and more for quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. No, there aren't sub-arrays. You can use `System.arraycopy` to copy part or all of one array to another.

Instead of arrays you can use Lists, in particular `ArrayList`. `List.subList` will give you a "view" into a portion of the original list. (as a view this means that if the original list is modified the sub-list will be too, and vice-versa).

B. No. For that kind of situation instead of having a separate variable b, it's probably better to have a method that computes b's value. Then, when you want to know b's value you call that method. If you want to get fancy you could even introduce some kind of caching, but that's an optimization (and best left for if/when you actually measure a performance problem).

Comment: +1 - Re part B: in modelling terms (e.g. using UML, MOF, EMF terminology), `b` would be described as a "derived attribute".  But you are right: Java does not provide any specific support for this, and you need to implement it as a method.

Answer (score 1):

A) The only way to do this as single operation is to use ArrayList. Otherwise what you doing is fine.

B) To update a value, you need to perform an assignment.  If you want this to happen magically, you can do that with an Observer/Observable pattern, but you still need to implement this, and its not going to be simpler than a simple line of code.

Answer (score 1):

> This one is hard to explain.

The terms you appear to be looking for are "value semantics" and "reference semantics". In Java, primitives (values of types int, char, double, etc.) have value semantics: the variable stores the actual value, so `b = a` makes a copy of the value, and `a += 1` increases that value, without affecting any other variable that just happens to hold the same value. However, objects (values that are instances of a class) have reference semantics: the variable actually just "labels" the value (stores a reference of some sort to it), so `b = a` gives the same name to the variable, and changing `a` (you can't overload operators in Java, so we can't make `a += 1` compile in this case) also changes `b`, because they are actually the same thing. (Although this will still not have any effect, of course, on any other objects that happen to be "equal" - whatever that actually means for that type.)

Java does provide objects called `Integer`, `Char`, `Double` etc. that have reference semantics and mirror the primitive types. However, they are **immutable** (i.e. cannot be changed), so they do not address this "problem".

Further, none of this will automatically keep two **different** values "in sync" with each other (i.e. related by some mathematical function). If you want `b` to always be equal to `a + 1` (or in general, something more complicated than that), no matter what happens to `a`, then you have to make sure of it yourself. There are a number of ways to do this, with varying complexity, and the right tool for the job depends on a variety of factors. But you should first consider *whether you actually want to keep `b` around at all*. There's a good chance that what you should really be doing is just writing a **function** `b()` that calculates and returns `a + 1` (or, again, whatever the actual relationship is).